# Customising email variables

Tags: magento2, email, variables

Is it possible to customer email variables? For example, there is a variable for Shipping description: `{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}`

In the email I want to change new lines `(\n)` to be line breaks `(<br>)` for the shipping description.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to add custom variable to sales email template ?

Comment: If that the best way to get what I want to achieve